# Golang time formatting to a particular timestamp

Tags: go

I'm trying to format a `time.Time` type to a particular time of yesterday (particularly 23:59:59)

I have one function which converts current time to IST

```
func getTimeInIST() time.Time {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
    now := time.Now().In(loc)
    return now
}
```

another function which converts to the day before

```
func GetYesterdaysDateFromTime() time.Time{
    return getTimeInIST().AddDate(0, 0, -1)
}
```

I want to format the above to a time stamp of date `2009-06-12 23:59:59`
for which I do

```
yesterday := common.GetYesterdaysDateFromTime()
yesterday.Format("2006-01-02 23:59:59")
```

but I get this `2019-06-11 118:589:589`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the correct `hh:mm:ss` *values* in the format, just like you're doing with the `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: That's not how formats work. Formats represent a time in a particular format; they don't *change* anything about the time value. If you want to show the time `23:59:59`, you need to set the time before you format it.

Comment: what is "common" defined as?

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/kFvzBU01FY7

Answer (score 0):

Your time format is wrong. The reference time in Go is [`Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

```
func getTimeInIST() time.Time {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
    now := time.Now().In(loc)
    return now
}
func GetYesterdaysDateFromTime() time.Time {
    return getTimeInIST().AddDate(0, 0, -1)
}

func main() {
    yesterday := GetYesterdaysDateFromTime()
    print(yesterday.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

This prints:

> 2019-06-11 20:37:04